# removing duplicates from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, array-unique

I want to remove duplicate elements from an array in php. Following is the structure of the array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => xllga@hotmail.com
            [1] => bounce@abc.com
            [2] => 20120416135504.21734.qmail@abc.com
            [3] => xllga@hotmail.com
            [4] => info@abc.com
            [5] => info@abc.com
            [6] => xllga@hotmail.com
            [7] => xllga@hotmail.com
        )

)
```

How to go about it ?

Comment: is this data being pulled back from a table using SQL? If so couldn't the problem be addressed there instead? (a la GROUP BY) to only recieve unique responses?

Comment: Try using array_unique in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$new_unique_array = array_unique($your_array[0]);
```

Hope that helps,
Stefan

Answer (score 7):

Try [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

**Code :**

```
<?php

$arr = array_unique($arr);

?>
```

---

> array **array_unique** ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING
>   ] )
>
> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

Comment: And for reference, [`array_unique` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 3):

Try [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$newArray = array_unique($oldArray);
```

From the docs:

> [`array_unique()`] Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

No array_unique() solution. not so smart:)

```
array_keys(array_flip($array));
```

If use your array, `$array = $yourArray[0];`